# Control Azure Service Bus Queue Message Reception

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

We have a distributed architecture and there is a native system which needs to be called. The challenge is the capacity of the system which is not scalable and cannot take on more load of requests at same time. We have implemented Service Bus queues, where there is a Message handler listening to this queue and makes a call to the native system. The current challenge is whenever a message posted in the queue, the message handler is immediately processing the request. However, We wanted to have a scenario to only process two requests at a time. Pick the two, process it and then move on to the next two. Does Service Bus Queue provide inbuilt option to control this or should we only be able to do with custom logic?

```
var options = new MessageHandlerOptions()
            {
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
                AutoComplete = false
            
            };
        client.RegisterMessageHandler(
            async (message, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //Handler to process
                    await client.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
                }
                catch
                {
                    await client.AbandonAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
                }

            }, options);
```

Answer (score 4):

Message Handler API is designed for concurrency. If you'd like to process two messages at any given point in time then the Handler API with maximum concurrency of two will be your answer. In case you need to process a batch of two messages at any given point in time, this API is not what you need. Rather, fall back to building your own message pump using a lower level API outlined in the answer provided by Mikolaj.

Careful with re-locking messages though. It's not a guaranteed operation as it's a client-side operation and if there's a communication network, currently, the broker will reset the lock and the message will be processed again by another competing consumer if you scale out. That is why scaling-out in your scenario is probably going to be a challenge.

Additional point is about lower level API of the `MessageReceiver` when it comes to receiving more than a single message - `ReceiveAsync(n)` does **not** guarantee `n` messages will be retrieved. If you absolutely have to have `n` messages, you'll need to loop to ensure there are `n` and no less.

And the last point about the management client and getting a queue message count - strongly suggest **not** to do that. The management client is not intended for frequent use at run-time. Rather, it's uses for occasional calls as these calls are very slow. Given you might end up with a single processing endpoint constrained to only two messages at a time (not even per second), these calls will add to the overall time to process.

Comment: I am thinking to use the MessageReceiver and use ReceiveAsync(2), do you mean the List may have count greater than two? getting number less than 2 is still fine, but its interesting to know ReceiveAsync(n) doesnt guarantee that count.

Comment: It's always less than N. Never greater.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Feldman I was able to control my inflow of messages, but have another issue. The API which has the message handler is attached to application insights. I was able to query and see only 2 msgs are being processed everytime, but both these processes are having same application insights Operation_Id. I was trying how do I will be able to get different operation id for seperate messages. One work around I have is, app insights operation_parent id is different which helps me to find the logs as per flow, but I am targeting operation id to be different for each message. any thoughts?

Comment: Given that you use a single operation to retrieve both messages it makes sense they'd have the same operation ID. Not entirely sure what's the context of your AppInsights usage. Therefore can't really suggest much. The one thing you might try is when prior to completing the messages set a custom property with a different value on each and see if custom properties are included by AppInsights in the metadata collection.

Comment: I have a work around already, though operation id is same, the operation parent Id is different which helps. I am thinking to implement and see if [ServiceBusQueueTrigger] SDK implementation might help, Thanks Sean.

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head I don't think anything like that is supported out of the box, so your best bet is to do it yourself.

I would suggest you look at the [`ReceiveAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver.receiveasync?view=azure-dotnet) method, which allows you to receive specific amount of messages (NOTE: I don't think it guarantees that if you specify that you want to retrieve 2 message it will always get you two. For instance, if there's just one message in the queue then it will probably return that one, even though you asked for two)

You could potentially use the `ReceiveAsync()` method in combination with [`PeekAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver.peekasync?view=azure-dotnet) method where you can also provide a number of messages you want to peek. If the peeked number of messages is 2 than you can call `ReceiveAsync()` with better chances of getting desired two messages.

Another way would be to have a look at the [`ManagementClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.managementclient?view=azure-dotnet) and the [`GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.managementclient.getqueueruntimeinfoasync?view=azure-dotnet) method of the queue, which will give you the information about the number of messages in the queue. With that info you could then call the `ReceiveAsync()` mentioned earlier.

However, be aware that if you have multiple receivers listening to the same queue then there's no guarantees that anything from above will work, as there's no way to determine if these messages were received by another process or not.

It might be that you will need to go with a more sophisticated way of handling this and receive one message, then keep it alive (renew lock etc.) until you get another message and then process them together.

I don't think I helped too much but maybe at least it will give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you Mikolaj, Let me try:)