# How to renew Service Bus message from Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, function, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I follow [Microsoft's document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) to setup (using c#) but message will be expired due to Service Bus queue’s lock duration.

`isSessionsEnabled` is false, my setting in `host.json is as below for reference:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "prefetchCount": 100,
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
              "autoComplete": true,
              "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
              // tried "00:00:55", "00:02:30", "00:05:00"
              "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:10:00"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to not implement `extensions` in `host.json` (as from document it will auto-renew the lock) but still does not work.

For reference, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65846738/how-does-message-locking-and-lock-renewal-work-in-azure-service-bus) mentioned that Microsoft's document may have something wrong but did not mention possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to renew the lock manually as its control by the run time of function.
Function can renew the message lock by itself.

If you have set `isSessionsEnabled`   to `true`, the `sessionHandlerOptions` will  honored. As you have set `isSessionsEnabled`  to `false`, then `messageHandlerOptions` will honored.

The  [Peeklock behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior) :

> When Functions runtime receieve a message in peek-lock mode
> it will call  `Complete`  on the message once the function finishes
> successfully, or calls  `Abandon`  if the function fails. If the
> function runs longer than the  `PeekLock`  timeout, the lock is
> automatically renewed as long as the function is running.
>
> The  `maxAutoRenewDuration`  is configurable in  *host.json*, which
> maps to  `OnMessageOptions.MaxAutoRenewDuration`
> Based on the documentation maximum allowed time is 5 minute
> whereas you can increase the Functions run time
> limit from the default of 5 minutes to 10 minutes. For Service Bus
> functions you wouldn’t want to do that, because you’d exceed the
> Service Bus renewal limit.

Please refer this for  further information about  [Message  expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-expiration#entity-level-expiration) .

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the signature of your function? I believe maxAutoRenewDuration only applies for functions receiving a single message, i.e. won't work for functions receiving an array/list of messages.

Comment: Hi @Josh, here is my signature of function:
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(QueueName, Connection = "ServiceBus")] Message msg, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
}

Comment: Ah ok, there goes that theory :(